# Amazon AWS SQS RetrieveMessage count low

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Why is the `Amazon SQS` message retrieval so low? I read that there is a maxiumum of `10 Messages` available per `RetrieveMessage Request`

We were looking for numbers much higher than this, possibly in the thousands.

**Note** We are implementing with `Go` so the capacity for concurrency is available.

Comment: why the downvote? its a clear and precise question

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the answer you want to hear, but in order to scale SQS to higher throughput you need to scale your number of consumers. It's in the SQS documentation titled [Increasing Throughput using Horizontal Scaling and Action Batching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-throughput-horizontal-scaling-and-batching.html)
:

> To achieve high throughput, you must scale message producers and
>   consumers horizontally (add more producers and consumers).

If you are using concurrency in go, just make more then one request for 10 messages.

Comment: But is that correct statement that SQS only provides 10 messages per request.